# Multiple OR Statements when filtering a Date SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below runs correctly without the additional `"OR"` parameters added.

The query result for SC, and CC are not formatting to the `WHERE` clause for some reason, and returning me several dates outside of my parameters. How should I change this syntax to ensure that my `WHERE` clause is affect the `OR` statements?

```
SELECT DISTINCT case_number, case_filed_date
FROM [case]
WHERE case_filed_date BETWEEN '2012/07/01' AND '2012/09/30'
AND case_number LIKE '%CA%' OR case_number LIKE '%SC%' OR case_number LIKE '%CC%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using brackets as `AND` has a higher precedence over `OR`:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT case_number, case_filed_date
FROM [case]
WHERE case_filed_date BETWEEN '2012/07/01' AND '2012/09/30'
AND 
(case_number LIKE '%CA%' OR case_number LIKE '%SC%' OR case_number LIKE '%CC%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parentheses

```
SELECT DISTINCT case_number, case_filed_date
FROM [case]
WHERE case_filed_date BETWEEN '2012/07/01' AND '2012/09/30'
AND 
(
    case_number LIKE '%CA%' OR case_number LIKE '%SC%' OR case_number LIKE '%CC%'
)
```

`and` binds stronger than `or`